# How to get Post with Comments Count in single query with CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, aggregation

How to get Post with Comments Count in single query with CouchDB?

I can use map-reduce to build standalone view `[{key: post_id, value: comments_count}]` but then I had to hit DB twice - one query to get the post, another to get comments_count.

There's also another way (Rails does this) - count comments manually, on the application server and save it in `comment_count` attribute of the post. But then we need to update the whole post document every time a new comment added or deleted.
It seems to me that CouchDB is not tuned for such a way, unlike RDBMS when we can update only the `comment_count` attribute in CouchDB we are forced to update the whole post document.

Maybe there's another way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The view's return json includes the document count as 'total_rows', so you don't need to compute anything yourself, just emit all the documents you want counted.

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
   {"id":...,"key":...,value:doc1},
   {"id":...,"key":...,value:doc2},
   {"id":...,"key":...,value:doc3}]
}
```

Comment: But I don't need to fetch all the comments, it's inefficient. For example - I want to display a list of posts with numbers of comments. If there will be 30 posts displayed on page - with such approach I also has to fetch all the comments for all 30 posts.

Comment: I think you're either stuck with 2 calls or more bandwidth.  If you throw both calls asynchronously from the browser, you'll have a small overhead for the extra connection but most of the latencies will overlap.

Comment: this is no good because in such case the comment counts will be invisible for clients without javascript